# Select rows with null value for a column from datatable

Tags: asp.net, datatable

Have an issue in selecting rows with a column value as null. I tried many options:

Dim dr() As DataRow = dt.Select("Col1 Is DBNull.Value","")

Dim dr() As DataRow = dt.Select("Col1 Is " & DBNull.Value,"")

None worked for me. Please help me with correct syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim dr() As DataRow = dt.Select("Col1 Is NULL")
```

ref: [DataColumn.Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)